# Unsubscribe Test - How to Check

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I just unsubscribed from email (using another personal address) through a new Profile center built with  SmartCapture.

Where can I check whether or not this subscriber (myself) has unsubscribed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search the [All Subscribers list](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/lists_for_interactive_marketing_hub/all_subscribers_list/) for their status, or query the [_Subscribers](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_subscribers/) Data view returning the `EmailAddress` and `Status`.

The query should look like this

```
SELECT
EmailAddress
,Status

FROM _Subscribers

WHERE EmailAddress = "EmailYouJustUnsusbcribed"
```

A caveat to this will be when the emailaddresses and subscriber keys are not the same. Then I would advise to query for the SubscriberKey and Status

If they have been successfully unsubscribed, then the status will be "`Unsubscribed"`

If you have a more advanced use case (or want to do things a bit harder and familiarise yourself with the SOAP APIs) you can use this [Subscriber SOAP Calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve_a_subscriber_via_the_web_service_api.htm).

Comment: Any indication on how long it takes for the MC system to update the record?  I would imagine it would be immediate, but I've been wrong before.

Comment: Should be immediate give or take the proverbial MC Lag